# Is this question too much about life?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

There seems to be a tension between having moral beliefs, real knowledge or not, and how people who don't share in them are more likely to get what they want. This in turn undermines my belief in the value of anything.

Has any philosopher discussed a way out of this?